# In Vaadin how can I set a style within a Label and NOT have it affect the whole page

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

So for example I set the following html code in my `Label`:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
label.setValue("<style> * { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; } </style> hello world");
```

The problem with the above code is that it sets the whole page to the Arial and NOT just the `Label`. If I use a `RichTextArea` then it ONLY sets the style to that component but for whatever reason any css styles defined in the `Label` are applied to the whole page...

FYI - If you set a `RichTextArea` to read only you get the exact same issue...

Comment: You must use the correct css selector. Using the * in your css is applying that style to all html tags -> whole page. Anywhy it's a strange idea to use the label in html mode and then use html and css inside it. There are separate methods to set content and css for a specific label

Comment: It's a user generated report. Basically instead of pipping it to a RichTextArea (which can do this) I want to pipe it so that it looks as though it's part of the page. It's all self contained using templates because that html snippet can then later be transformed into a PDF file, etc.

Comment: Does it work if you use inline style like this: `<span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">`?

Comment: Yes, `style` will work. And I hope OP is aware that this is a hack and now they are responsible to prevent XSS in that label.

Comment: That's why I want to keep it completely self-contained like the RichTextArea component does. That's why I even tried RichTextArea with setReadOnly(true) but that resulted in basically the same time. If it's not readOnly than any CSS seems to be contained to the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up using was a BrowserFrame. The only thing is that the BrowserFrame's height cannot be resized dynamically like a Label with a -1px.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding the style inline. Use the `addStyleName` method that hangs off the Vaadin Components.

**Example**

**Java:**

```
Label label = new Label();
label.addStyleName("my-custom-style");
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-custom-style {
    font-size: 12px:
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

To include a custom StyleSheet.

- Add `@StyleSheet("my-style-sheet.css")` to the top of your Class / UI
- Create the CSS file in your resources folder under the same package structure.

**Edit:**

As this is being used in a generated report and you can't use the above solution:

Rather than using the style tag like you have. If you wrap your text in a span tag you can use inline style to apply it specifically to that Label:

```
label.setValue("<span style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;\">Your text here</span>");
```

**Note:** Please note that by using the method. You're opening yourself up to potential HTML Injection and will need to put something in place to prevent this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because it's a user generated report

Answer (score 3):

Isolating some element in the HTML tree is not really a Vaadin problem.  One way to solve it in HTML5, is the use of an [`iframe`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html) with a `srcdoc` attribute (or alternatively `src="data:..."`).

Here is an example how to use it with Vaadin8, **but be warned: once you deal with HTML in a `Label` it is *your* responsibility to quote/encode everything there properly -- especially, since you mentioned, that all that content is from a user!**

```
// run with `spring run --watch <file>.groovy`
@Grapes([
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:8.1.6'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:8.1.6'),
])

import com.vaadin.ui.*
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.*
import com.vaadin.shared.*
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.ContentMode


@com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI
@com.vaadin.annotations.Theme("valo")
class MyUI extends UI {
        protected void init(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new VerticalLayout(
            new Label("<h1>Hello</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum</p>", ContentMode.HTML),
            new Label("""
                <iframe srcdoc="
                    <style type='text/css'>* { font-family: monospace; font-size: 36pt; background-color: green; }</style>
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                "></iframe>
            """, ContentMode.HTML),
            new Label("<h1>Hello</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum</p>", ContentMode.HTML),
        ))  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are not supposed to add styles inline to Vaadin components. You're supposed to add style definitions in a CSS file in your theme or custom CSS file and them as @Jay mentioned.

If you really want to use inline style definitions, then you have to use a `CssLayout` for it:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-csslayout.html

Comment: It's a user generated report that can contain styles

Comment: In that case, as I said, look into `CssLayout`. There's a sample in the docs that shows how to inject custom CSS for your elements.